# EditText not working in text android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm facing an issue regarding `EditText`.

`EditText` is not working in couple of android devices when `inputType:Text / TextMultiline/ TextPersonName.`
but when you use `inputType:Number` 
It works in all devices 
what is the issue?

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Quantity 1Kg Meat etc"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
              android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Firstly it didn't show the keyboard
then i use this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

after this i can't edit the text fields 
if inputType:number then it works

One thing i want to add more is i'm using this in custom `ListView`

Comment: `EditText is not working in couple of android devices when inputType:Text / TextMultiline/ TextPersonName.` what you mean exactly ?

Comment: If i use `android:inputType: Text` . Then its not working. means only showing the keyboard but unable to edit when i click on the field i'm unable to edit that

Comment: I also tried this. i got the issue. if mobile text prediction is on then editText unable to edit field

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with   `android:textIsSelectable="true"` try to remove and check

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:hint="Quantity 1Kg Meat etc"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

                android:clickable="true"
              android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: i also tried this. i got the issue. if mobile text prediction is on then editText unable to edit this

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text"
 android:focusable="true"
```

Working solution
If mobile text prediction is on then use above inputType to edit textfields